# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator ( Applies numeric condition to varchar column )

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a varchar column in oracle DB that stores numeric and character values.

```
ID : VALUE
01 : 12
02 : 15
03 : 16
04 : 08
05 : Positive
```

I got error when I used numeric condition in where clause.

```
WHERE VALUE > 10
```

How can i fix this situation?

Comment: Mixing numeric and character values is a mess. Note that character comparison makes 2 > 10.

Comment: Do you consider `Positive` greater or smaller than 10?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Oracle 12cR2 then you can use `default value` when conversion error happens.

```
SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE AS
  2  (SELECT '01' AS ID , '12' AS VALUE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  3  SELECT '02', '15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  4  SELECT '03', '16' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  5  SELECT '04', '08' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  6  SELECT '05', 'Positive' FROM DUAL);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE
  2  where TO_NUMBER(value DEFAULT -1 ON CONVERSION ERROR) > 10;

ID VALUE
-- --------
01 12
02 15
03 16
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, your `value` column consists of character values.

To apply correct numeric condition on it, you have to turn it into number:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE 10 < CASE value 
              WHEN 'Positive' THEN null 
              WHEN 'Negative' THEN null 
              ELSE TO_NUMBER(value) 
            END
```

Comment: It works if i have only three possible entries ( numeric , positive and negative).

Comment: @Nawaf yes, that's what I concluded from example in question. Do you have more types of value? If yes, with `TO_NUMBER()` you can only convert strings made of numeric characters. There is no way to precisely compare strings with non numeric characters either than converting them manually (aka using `CASE`) or ignoring them (similar to what Tejash posted)